# Query timestamp range using elasticsearch-dsl-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have an elasticsearch range query that I'd like to translate into [elasticsearch-dsl](https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch-dsl/):

#### Elasticsearch Python API

```py
{"range": 
    {"@timestamp": 
        {"gte": 1570258800000, 
         "lte": 1571036400000, 
         "format": "epoch_millis"
        }
     }
 }
```

#### Elasticsearch-DSL-Py Query?

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch(<connection_details>)

s = Search(using=client, index="my-index") \
    .query("???")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch(<connection_details>)

s = Search(using=client, index="my-index") \
    .filter('range' ,  **{'@timestamp': {'gte': 1570258800000 , 'lt': 1571036400000, 'format' : 'epoch_millis'}})
```

Comment: Is it possible to use string values as starting and ending date? do I need to specify the format if so ?

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.query('range', **{'@timestamp': {'gte': ...}})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also supply the date in string format (YYYY-MM-DD). Here's a snippet

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch()

date_from = '2022-10-01' # Oct 01, 2022
date_to = '2022-10-05' # Oct 05, 2022

s = Search(using=client)
s = s.query('range', **{'published': {'gte': date_from, 'lte': date_to}})
```